# Python - merging data in two tables

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

I would like to merge data in tables with python(python 3.4).
My sample data is like below, and I want to get that kind of result table.

**[Table 1]**

```
Name1 Name2
AAAA XXXX
BBBB YYYY
CCCC ZZZZ
```

**[Table 2]**

```
Index1 Sample1 Sample2 Sample3
AAAA 10 20 30
BBBB 25 25 25
CCCC 30 31 32
XXXX 27 29 31
YYYY 45 21 56
ZZZZ 48 24 10
```

**[Result Table]**

```
Index2 Sample1 Sample2 Sample3
AAAA+XXXX 37 49 61
BBBB+YYYY 70 46 81
CCCC+ZZZZ 78 55 42
```

Although it seems to be a simple problem, I could not find good solutions Since I am a newbie in python and I am not familiar to python libraries. It may be easy if I use SQL on DB, but I would like to solve it without DB.
Does anyone have good idea?

Comment: I recommend first reading "Table 2" into a relational datatype, like a python dictionary. With that you have your key value pairs. Then you can parse the "Table 1" file to see which values you want to add together.

Comment: Have a look at [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). In particular, the section on [DataFrame joining and merging](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging).

Comment: How is the data in tables stored? In a `.txt` file ?

Comment: @enpenax That seems to be a good idea, but I am afraid that the table 2 is in fact very large(more than 1GB).

Comment: @Evert Thank you for your advice. Pandas seems to be very strong at dealing with dataframe. I should take a look at it.

Comment: If you want to do these kind of things with 1GB sized tables, it definitely sounds like you'd want to use Pandas.

Comment: @ZdaR Basically it is space seperated .txt file.

Comment: @ToBeSpecific how big is Table 1? You cannot avoid storing either in memory, else runtime will be crazy. If Table 1 is reasonably small you can still do it cleverly in 1 run through Table 2. If it is not you will need to use a framework that deals with this kind of data (e.g. Pandas) or work with sqlite.

Comment: @Evert I think Pandas can be a nice solution , althogh I have to study about it for a while. I hope it could cover big data without problem. Thank you for your recommandation.

Comment: @enpenax Althogh Table 1 is smaller than Table 2, but it is still large(About 300MB and tables are still expandable). It seems that dealing with this kind of big file directly is not nice, so I am thinking of checking Pandas as you and Evert recommended. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following `csv` approach will work for your sample data:

```
import csv

with open('table2.txt', 'r') as f_table2:
    csv_table2 = csv.reader(f_table2, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    table2_header = next(csv_table2)
    table2_data = {cols[0] : cols[1:] for cols in csv_table2}

with open('table1.txt', 'r') as f_table1, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='\n') as f_output:
    csv_table1 = csv.reader(f_table1, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    table1_header = next(csv_table1)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(table2_header)

    csv_output.writerows(
        ['{}+{}'.format(cols[0], cols[1])] + [int(x) + int(y) for x, y in zip(table2_data[cols[0]], table2_data[cols[1]])] for cols in csv_table1)
```

This will give you an output CSV file as follows:

```
Index1,Sample1,Sample2,Sample3
AAAA+XXXX,37,49,61
BBBB+YYYY,70,46,81
CCCC+ZZZZ,78,55,42
```

Tested using Python 3.4.3

Comment: csv module seems to be also very useful for dealing with txt files. Your code works well with my sample. I'd like to test both csv approach and pandas approach with bigger dataset. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with pure python (without 3rd party libraries, such as numpy), it would be possible to do it this way:

```
class Entry:
    def __init__(self, index, sample1, sample2, sample3):
        self.index = index
        self.sample1 = sample1
        self.sample2 = sample2
        self.sample3 = sample3

    def __add__(self, other):
        return '{index2} {sample1} {sample2} {sample3}'.format(
            index2=self.index + '+' + other.index,
            sample1=self.sample1 + other.sample1,
            sample2=self.sample2 + other.sample2,
            sample3=self.sample3 + other.sample3,
        )


def read_table(path_to_data):
    def extract_body(content):
        return [e.strip().split(' ') for e in content[1:]]

    with open(path_to_data, 'r') as f:
        content = f.readlines()
    return extract_body(content)


content1 = read_table('data1.txt')
content2 = read_table('data2.txt')

entries = [Entry(e[0], int(e[1]), int(e[2]), int(e[3])) for e in content2]

# output
print('Index2 Sample1 Sample2 Sample3')

for line in content1:
    entry1 = next(e for e in entries if e.index == line[0])
    entry2 = next(e for e in entries if e.index == line[1])

    print(entry1 + entry2)
```

Comment: As I am a newbie in python, I would like to utilize ready-made libraries as much as possible. However, I am surprised that you did it with pure python without data handling libraries and learned a little bit about how to deal with this kind of work. Thank you for your help.